# Highslide close button position

Tags: highslide

Hello. I need to add close button to the top right corner of highslide popup window. I add to config:

```
hs.registerOverlay({
    html: '<div class="closebutton" onclick="return hs.close(this)" title="Close"></div>',
    position: 'top right',
    useOnHtml: true,
    fade: 2 // fading the semi-transparent overlay looks bad in IE
});
```

But on some pages popup window has a caption text on the right panel, and numbering above the photo. And this button positioned relative to photo, not to the whole window. Maybe overlay can be added to one element higher in the DOM (class highslide-wrapper)? This could solve my issue.

offsetX and offsetY work only on pages with caption on the right panel.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We’ve found that the easiest way to add a layer that respects highslide-heading with different heights, rightpanel caption etc, is to use jQuery: create a div, style it and append it to the highslide-wrapper.
Add this to your Highslide settings:

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterExpand = function (sender) {
    $('<div onclick="return hs.close(this)" title="Close"></div>').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '-15px',
        right: '-15px',
        height: '30px',
        width: '30px',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        background: 'url(/highslide/graphics/close.png)', // adjust the path if necessary
        zIndex: 20
    }).appendTo(sender.wrapper);
};
```

**Note: This solution requires highslide-full.js and jQuery.**